# How to dynamically grow canvas as user scrolls down page

Tags: javascript, canvas, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension that appends a canvas over whatever webpage is open. It does this by appending the canvas to the top of the body, and setting its dimemsions as the window height and width so that the user can draw over top of the page. The problem is that this only makes the canvas cover what part of the page is first loaded. I want to keep adding to the canvas's height when the user scrolls down the page. What is a good way to do this? I would appreciate any suggestions.

```
var canvasDiv = document.createElement("div");
canvasDiv.innerHTML = "<div><canvas id='xyz149'></canvas></div>";
document.body.insertBefore(canvasDiv, document.body.firstChild);
var canvas = document.getElementById("xyz149");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.style.position = "absolute";
canvas.style.zIndex = 200;
ctx.canvas.width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
ctx.canvas.height = (window.innerHeight > 0) ? window.innerHeight : screen.height;
```

I think I should add that making more than one canvas will be a last resort for me because I would like the user to be able to draw across the whole canvas. I am also not currently using Jquery in the extension. Thanks!

UPDATE:

This is the event listener I used to grow the canvas when the user scrolls.

```
var originalCanvasHeight = ctx.canvas.height;
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  ctx.canvas.height = originalCanvasHeight + document.body.scrollTop;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if((window.innerHeight + document.body.scrollTop) > document.body.offsetHeight){
// User is at the bottom of the page, get canvas element and increase the height
}
```

You'll want to add something simmilar to the above and then either find how much space has been added or if you want to increase the canvas in increments as they scroll.

Note: This approach would need further work if the user starts and doesn't need to scroll at all, though you could manipulate it to start growing straight away.

Comment: Thanks. Document.body.scrollTop was exactly what I was looking for. I ended up creating an event listener for the scroll event.